# change AsyncTask to Execute Service

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I build a project for using Room database. I follow the tutorial from youtube but get a problem when call AsyncTask it said deprecated. I want to change it to Execute. I have learned documents but I do not clearly understand.

this is my part of my code that I want to modify to execute in the background.

private  static class InsertTripAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Trip, Void, Void>{

```
    private TripDao tripDao;

    private InsertTripAsyncTask(TripDao tripDao) {
        this.tripDao = tripDao;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Trip... trips) {
        tripDao.insert(trips[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

thank you for reading this is my first Ask on StackOverflow

Comment: even if it says DEPRECATED it will work. Is your code working or do you get an error?

Comment: It work. I don't get any error but I want to change it to Execute medthod .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

you can execute Asynctask in background by creating a method and invoking the `InsertTripAsyncTask()` constructor inside the method as follows:

```
public void insert(Trip trip){
     new InsertTripAsyncTask(tripDao).execute(trip);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use AsyncTask I want to change it to the Executor.